# Is it possible to put two numbers int one cell of an array?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it was possible to input two numbers into one cell of an array. Like in the case of having two points on a graph (1,-2) can I put them into the same cell and if so how? Thank you.

Comment: use `struct Point {int x; int y;};`

Comment: @BryanChen with `vector<Point>` if possible!

Comment: Why do people put answers in comments?  The comment box clearly says not to do that before you start typing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: because writing **proper** answer takes longer.

Comment: @SigTerm: Okay, so why do people put partial answers in comments?  Unless they just don't have time to make a proper answer, but have some novel idea which they're worried nobody else will think of.  And let's face it, using a struct is not that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: In general case, I guess the idea is to give starting point to the OP or to somebody else who has more time on their hands. The op can start fixing the problem immediately, and somebody else (or maybe OP himself) will write the answer, which will get accepted. Doesn't sound bad to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve this.  Here are three common ones, all of which use a C array on the stack:

1. `int graph[NUMEL][2];`
2. `struct { int x, y; } graph[NUMEL];`
3. `std::pair<int,int> graph[NUMEL];`